# Aggregating a QuerySet to get Sum of FileFields size

Tags: python, django, mongodb, gridfs

I am using django-nonrel, Postgre as a database and Mongo as file store.

my Model look like this and is working properly

```
class Doc(models.Model):
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    file = models.FileField(storage=gridfs_storage, upload_to='/')
```

and is working properly

```
Doc.objects.all()[0].file.size
108776
```

Now I am trying to aggregate the size to get the total size of a query set.

I have tried

```
Doc.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('file__size'))
```

but this throw

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/zoidberg/dev/backus/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 321, in aggregate
    is_summary=True)
  File "/Users/zoidberg/dev/backus/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 974, in add_aggregate
    field_list, opts, self.get_initial_alias(), False)
  File "/Users/zoidberg/dev/backus/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1417, in setup_joins
    raise FieldError("Join on field %r not permitted. Did you misspell %r for the lookup type?" % (name, names[pos + 1]))
FieldError: Join on field 'file' not permitted. Did you misspell 'size' for the lookup type?
    enter code here
```

any idea if that is possible using the ORM or I d have to iterate of the files myself ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to do this with the ORM since it can only generate aggregations against database fields, while `file.size` is a dynamic attribute provided by the storage backend.

That said, you're probably better of saving this information in your actual database at upload time, so you can avoid the overhead of iterating over all files.

```
class Doc(models.Model):
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    file = models.FileField(storage=gridfs_storage, upload_to='/')
    file_size = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.file_size = self.file.size
        super(Doc, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now aggregations work as expected since you're dealing with a database field:

```
Doc.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('file_size'))
```

Comment: Right in the mean time I was using `sum([f.file.size for f in Doc.objects.all()])` but your solution sounds more reasonable. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

A hcalves pointed out this is not possible using the straight ORM.  I'm assuming your db is already done and set so why can't you just do this?

```
total_size = sum([ x.file.size for x in Doc.objects.all() ])
```

Just a thought?

Comment: yes, I falled back to that until hcalves proposed his solution , just did not feel the "django" way :) Project is nowhere near production so I can change my model

Comment: Also offloading the sum to the database might be wiser than doing it app side